# Qt writing to QTextStream pointer

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, stream

I want to include a file handle and stream as my class' private members.

```
class Window : public QMainWindow, private Ui::Window
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
    .
    .
    .
    private:
        QFile * outputFile;
        QTextStream * outputFileStream;
};
```

I then want to initialize the handle and stream in the constructor:

```
Window::Window(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);
    outputFile = new QFile("/path/to/file.log");
    outputFile->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    outputFileStream = new QTextStream(outputFile);
    *outputFileStream << "=======List=======\n\n";
}
```

This creates the file, but writes nothing to it.  However, when I use a pointer for the QFile, but not the QTextStream, it works:

```
Window::Window(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupUi(this);
    outputFile = new QFile("/path/to/file.log");
    outputFile->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    QTextStream outputFileStream(&outputFile);
    outputFileStream << "=======List=======\n\n";
}
```

This is not very useful because I can't write to this stream later in the class's main function.  The two seem equivalent to me, but obviously are not.

I'm not set on this implementation.  If someone has a suggestion on a better way of doing this (i.e. using static or something) that's also great.

Comment: Does this work? (*outputFileStream) << "=======List=======\n\n";

Comment: I tried that.  No dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with the pointer by flushing the outputFileStream.

Comment: That makes sense. In the first instance, you're keeping the text stream object open so the internal buffer fills up till it's full and only then flushes data to the file. In the local version, the text stream object is destroyed when you leave the constructor and will flush it's internal buffer to the file in it's destructor.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to know how to use pointer with QTextStream.
Here is how i did this :

```
outputFileStream->setString(new QString("Your string"));
```